# Not getting much speedup from Cython

Tags: python, cython, kalman-filter

I'm trying to convert some code from an existing library to apply an optimal Kalman Filter to a large number of segments.  Here is the original library:

https://github.com/rlabbe/filterpy/blob/master/filterpy/kalman/kalman_filter.py

First, here's how the smoothed filter could be applied using the original library.

```
import numpy as np
from filterpy.kalman import KalmanFilter as KF

def build_kf():
    kf = KF(dim_x=2, dim_z=1)
    kf.x = np.array([arr[0], 0])
    kf.F = np.array([[1.,1.],
                      [0.,1.]])
    kf.H = np.array([[1.,0.]])
    return kf

def apply_smoother(arr):
    kf = build_kf()
    mu, cov, _, _ = kf.batch_filter(arr)
    return kf.rts_smoother(mu, cov)[0][:,0]
```

Here's an attempt at a Cython implementation.  Rather than using the class-based implementation, it's purely functional.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division

from copy import deepcopy
from math import log, exp, sqrt
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

def rts_smoother(np.ndarray Xs, 
                 np.ndarray Ps, 
                 np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] F, 
                 np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] Q, 
                 inv=np.linalg.inv):

    if len(Xs) != len(Ps):
        raise ValueError('length of Xs and Ps must be the same')

    cdef int n = Xs.shape[0]
    cdef int dim_x = Xs.shape[1]

    # smoother gain
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] K = zeros((n, dim_x, dim_x))
    
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] x = Xs.copy()
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] P = Ps.copy()
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] Pp = Ps.copy()
    
    for k in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        Pp[k] = dot(dot(F, P[k]), F.T) + Q

        K[k]  = dot(dot(P[k], F.T), inv(Pp[k]))
        x[k] += dot(K[k], x[k+1] - dot(F, x[k]))
        P[k] += dot(dot(K[k], P[k+1] - Pp[k]), K[k].T)

    return (x, P, K, Pp)

def apply_smoother(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] zs, int dim_x=1, int dim_z=1, int dim_u=0):

    
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] x = np.zeros((dim_x, 1), dtype=float)        # state
    x[0,0] = zs[0]
    
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] P = np.eye(dim_x, dtype=float)               # uncertainty covariance
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] Q = np.eye(dim_x, dtype=float)               # process uncertainty
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] F = np.eye(dim_x, dtype=float)               # state transition matrix
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] H = np.zeros((dim_z, dim_x), dtype=float)    # measurement function
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] R = np.eye(dim_z, dtype=float)               # measurement uncertainty
    cdef DTYPE_t _alpha_sq = 1.               # fading memory control
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] M = np.zeros((dim_x, dim_z), dtype=float) # process-measurement cross correlation
    
    if dim_x == 1:
        H = np.ones((dim_z, dim_x), dtype=float)
    else:
        F = np.array([[1.,1.],
                      [0.,1.]], dtype=float)
        H = np.array([[1.,0.]], dtype=float)
        

    # gain and residual are computed during the innovation step. We
    # save them so that in case you want to inspect them for various
    # purposes
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] K = np.zeros((dim_x, dim_z), dtype=float) # kalman gain
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] y = np.zeros((dim_z, 1), dtype=float)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] S = np.zeros((dim_z, dim_z), dtype=float) # system uncertainty
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] SI = np.zeros((dim_z, dim_z), dtype=float) # inverse system uncertainty

    # identity matrix. Do not alter this.
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] _I = np.eye(dim_x, dtype=float)

    # these will always be a copy of x,P after predict() is called
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] x_prior = x.copy()
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] P_prior = P.copy()

    # these will always be a copy of x,P after update() is called
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] x_post = x.copy()
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] P_post = P.copy()

    # Only computed only if requested via property
    cdef DTYPE_t _log_likelihood = log(sys.float_info.min)
    cdef DTYPE_t _likelihood = sys.float_info.min
    # self._mahalanobis = None

    inv = np.linalg.inv

    
    cdef int n = np.size(zs, 0)
    
    
    # mean estimates from Kalman Filter
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] means
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] means_p
    
    means = zeros((n, dim_x, 1))
    means_p = zeros((n, dim_x, 1))

    # state covariances from Kalman Filter
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] covariances = zeros((n, dim_x, dim_x), dtype=float)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] covariances_p = zeros((n, dim_x, dim_x), dtype=float)
    
    cdef DTYPE_t z
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] I_KH
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] PHT
    
    
    for i in range(zs.size):

        z = zs[i]

        # ---------------- predict ----------------
        
        x = np.dot(F, x)
        P = _alpha_sq * np.dot(np.dot(F, P), F.T) + Q

        means_p[i, :] = x
        covariances_p[i, :, :] = P
        
        
        # ---------------- update ----------------
        
        # y = z - Hx
        # error (residual) between measurement and prediction
        y = z - np.dot(H, x)
        
        # common subexpression for speed
        PHT = np.dot(P, H.T)

        # S = HPH' + R
        # project system uncertainty into measurement space
        S = dot(H, PHT) + R
        SI = inv(S)
        # K = PH'inv(S)
        # map system uncertainty into kalman gain
        K = np.dot(PHT, SI)

        # x = x + Ky
        # predict new x with residual scaled by the kalman gain
        x = x + np.dot(K, y)

        # P = (I-KH)P(I-KH)' + KRK'
        # This is more numerically stable
        # and works for non-optimal K vs the equation
        # P = (I-KH)P usually seen in the literature.

        I_KH = _I - np.dot(K, H)
        P = np.dot(np.dot(I_KH, P), I_KH.T) + np.dot(dot(K, R), K.T)
        
        means[i, :] = x
        covariances[i, :, :] = P
        
       
    means = rts_smoother(means, covariances, F, Q)[0][:,0]
    return means
```

The Cython implementation appears to be working (giving the same values), but I only get about a 25% or so speedup when testing each of the above with something like this:

```
for i in range(1000):
    arr = np.arange(50).astype(float)
    apply_smoother(arr)
```

Is there anything here that might be preventing more of a speedup?

Comment: Most of your real work is in numpy, which is already in C (or Fortran) and won't be affected.  Your Python is just plumbing.  Amdahl's Law.

Comment: Okay, I thought that could be a factor, but there's material out there talking about how even numpy can be sped up with Cython.

Comment: Where Cython helps is if you have to index individual elements out of the Numpy arrays (show in Python, can be really quick in Cython). In this case you might get a small speedup by actually deleting most of the `cdef` types - Cython isn't able to make use of it, but is spending time checking it